# How can I set the RewriteModule in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewrite-module

I will present a to the point example.

I have a domain name as: www.abc.com

And another domain name as: www.123.com

**Now i want to write a rewritemodule in .htaccess for the following case:**

If i request a url like: www.123.com/xyz

It will redirect my request to www.abc.com/track/index.php?ext=xyz

Also please tell me on which directory i should keep that .htaccess file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the root folder of www.123.com, you would create an htaccess file with the following line:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*) www.abc.com/track/index.php?ext=$1
```

Since you are doing an external redirect, it is not necessary to use mod_rewrite.

Comment: Internal Server Error.

Let me explain you the structure.

www.abc.com is pointing at: home/abc/public_html/
www.123.com is pointing at: home/abc/track/

I want www.123.com/xyz  to point at
www.abc.com/track/index.php?ext=xyx [home/abc/public_html/track/index.php]

www.123.com is an addon domain of www.abc.com